Microsoft Store doesn't load list of installed apps
Everything loads there except the tab called Downloads (marked in blue when clicked). Clicking Get Updates also loads forever.
Any idea how to fix this? It happened to me once at another computer and it just fixed itself later on.
The following didn't help:

Running wsreset didn't help
Deleting %LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalCache (meanwhile, deleting other subfolders there just prevented the store from getting even opened).
Signing out then in inside the store


